# Not able to get response while calling ssl enabled restful wcf service using jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

```
function Login() {
            debugger;
            var LoginInfo = JSON.stringify({ "strAccountName": "#####", "strPassword": "######", "strDeviceId": "###############" });
            var strUriGet = "https://service.domain.com/OneView/dev/OneviewClient.svc/Login";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: strUriGet,
                data: LoginInfo,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                processData: true,
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("success..." + data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, exception) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

The above method i am calling to login the service, i am able to consume the service using HttpClient.PostJsonAsAsync but i am not able to consume the service using jquery ajax call, i am receiving status code 200 but response is blank.
Service is hosted at the subdomain with https (which has a valid certificate) and my wcf service is restful. I have set security mode to "Transport".

Comment: what do you see in the `alert()`? or better to use `console.log(data)`

Comment: receiving undefined, as i told i am getting statuscode 200 ok than also it falls in error block.

Comment: I am not able to understand why i am not able to request the ssl enabled wcf service via ajax call.

Comment: this is a crossdomain request use `jsonp` and see if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but jsonp is not working as the methods are defined as post, and i got it working by adding an element to allow ajax call <enableWebScript /> to the web.config now it working like a charm.